# Do Cedric Diggory and Charles Weasley have the same personalities (as demonstrated by which wands chose them)?

Tags: harry-potter

Since Cedric Diggory's wand and Charles' Weasley's wand have the same wand wood and same wand core, can we assume their personalities to be similar? Since wands choose the wizard, and the two wands are the same type of wood and core, does that imply a similarity in their personalities, as the similar wands chose them?

Comment: Fairly sure Olivander says that the wand chooses the wizard/witch

Comment: @SpacePhoenix - Sure, but based on their personalities

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no. If we take Ollivander's word (via JKR) as gospel on the subject there are essentially four separate characteristics of a wand that determine its suitability for an individual wizard and (critically) none can be considered entirely in isolation of the others;

> However, no single aspect of wand composition should be considered in isolation of all the others, and **the type of wood, the core and the flexibility may either counterbalance or enhance the attributes of the wand’s length.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Wand Lengths & Flexibility By J.K. Rowling](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-lengths-and-flexibilit)</sup></sub>

While we would certainly expect both Cedric and Charles to have *similar* personality types, the fact that [Charles Weasley's wand](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Ronald_Weasley%27s_first_wand) was slightly smaller and less flexible than [Cedric Diggory's wand](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Cedric_Diggory%27s_wand) may well have something to say about their ways in which these attributes are expressed in the individual.

> The ash wand cleaves to its one true master and ought not to be passed on or gifted from the original owner, because it will lose power and skill. This tendency is extreme if the core is of unicorn. Old superstitions regarding wands rarely bear close examination, but I find that the old rhyme regarding rowan, chestnut, ash and hazel wands (rowan gossips, chestnut drones, ash is stubborn, hazel moans) contains a small nugget of truth. Those witches and wizards best suited to ash wands are not, in my experience, lightly swayed from their beliefs or purposes. However, the brash or over-confident witch or wizard, who often insists on trying wands of this prestigious wood, will be disappointed by its effects. The ideal owner may be stubborn, and will certainly be courageous, but never crass or arrogant.
>
> <sub><sup>[Wand Woods By J.K. Rowling](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-woods)</sup></sub>

and

> Wand flexibility or rigidity denotes the degree of adaptability and willingness to change possessed by the wand-and-owner pair – although, again, this factor ought not to be considered separately from the wand wood, core and length, nor of the owner’s life experience and style of magic, all of which will combine to make the wand in question unique.
>
> <sub><sup>[Wand Lengths & Flexibility By J.K. Rowling](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-lengths-and-flexibilit)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes, because wand woods and cores indicate very similar, and specific, personality traits (see these links to Pottermore https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-woods  and https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-cores) but the length and flexibility were different, insinuating that
Cedric Driggorys wand, that was more flexible and a bit longer, was more open-minded and had a bigger personality, whereas Charlie Weasley was a bit close minded and had a "smaller personality."
However, they would still be similar because Ash wands prefer owners who are bold but never arrogant, and also very kind, so thats where the similaritys would be.